# How to handle PUT HTTP request in Vapor?

Tags: swift, macos, rest, vapor

The only way I've found to update a record in Vapor is this:

```
drop.get("update") { request in

  guard var first = try Acronym.query().first(),
    let long = request.data["long"]?.string else {
    throw Abort.badRequest
  }
  first.long = long
  try first.save()
  return first

}
```

However it's not a very RESTful way of doing it since it's performing a GET request with a parameter instead of a PUT request.

How does one perform a PUT request in Vapor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
drop.put("update") { request in
  guard var first = try Acronym.query().first(),
    let long = request.data["long"]?.string else {
    throw Abort.badRequest
  }

  first.long = long
  try first.save()

  return first
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, performing PUT, as well as other HTTP methods are as simple as changing `.get()` or `.post()` to `.put()` or any other HTTP methods.

As for my question, to create a PUT function in Vapor, just simply add a `.put` method that takes an `Int` (Or String, or any data type you'd like), and accept a `JSON` (Or whatever format you'd like), and simply update like it's a POST request.